# SSIS logging to package report

Tags: logging, ssis, report

I'm a C# / BizTalk developer, but I inherited 2 SSIS packages, one on Sql Server 2016 and one on Sql Server 2017. Both packages use an FTP task to send collected data to the same destination.

In the package on Sql Server 2016 I get the following error, visible in the package execution report:

```
FTP:Error: Unable to send files using "FTP Connection Manager".
```

In the package on Sql Server 2017, a additional error entry is present, as follows:

```
<Package name>:Error: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description:
200 Type set to I.
200 PORT command successful.
553 /filename.csv: Permission denied
```

Followed by the same entry as on the other system:

```
FTP:Error: Unable to send files using "FTP Connection Manager".
```

No error handlers are present on either the package level or the FTP task level. The second case gave me useful info for the FTP admin to find out what the problem was, but the other one (not the same problem unfortunately :-) ) gives no real clues for him to find out what might be going wrong.

My question is: what could cause the difference in the logged information? Is it just that the 2017 version logs more extensively to its report data? Or is there a hidden setting, either in the package source code, in the SSIS package or job settings in Sql Server Management Studio, or maybe somewhere else, that makes a package store more details in its report when an error is encountered?

Thanks for any insights or pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Not hidden per se but there are a variety of knobs and dials one can fiddle with.

Assuming both packages run as jobs scheduled through SQL Agent, and further assuming we're using the package deployment model (which seems a given with your reference to the Execution Report), you have the ability to specify the package logging level per execution. Since it's a job, all runs will have the same log level until acted upon.

Out of the box, there are 4 levels: None, Basic, Performance, and Verbose with Basic as the default. What those mean are called out on MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging?view=sql-server-ver16#select-a-logging-level

With 2016, you have the ability to create your own logging levels so you can mashup Basic with some performance counters or whatever level of granularity your organization needs. Tim does a good job illustrating this https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2016/12/22/ssis-custom-logging-levels/

Off the top of my head, I can't imagine that Microsoft spent engineering dollars improving the FTP component between 2016 and 2017 but that *could* account for the difference in logging of available information but I doubt it.

It could be that someone chose to use the Execute Process Task for the 2017 package and just called the FTP process from the command line. The error information is the output (StandardOutput or StandardError) of that task that is getting raised to the caller.

Along those lines, they could have chosen to use a third party component for FTP in the 2017 package and that can account for the different level of verbosity from the component for errors.

Those are my quick places to check before I head to a day of meetings but the likeliest culprit is the logging level. Script the job and check what the value is and compare between servers. If that still hasn't illuminated the difference, edit your question with screenshots of both packages so I can see how FTP is being performed. Add the job definitions and we might need to see the details from the SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages for the failed executions and sift through the data.